# Readpast lock in memory optimized table in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, locking, oltp

I have a big problem in working with table in memory in SQL Server 2014.

I know that there is no readpast lock in SQL Server. but in some scenarios it can cause decrease in performance.

Suppose that there are 20 records in one table. Each record has one column `LockStatus` with an initial value of `Wait`.

If two consumers want to pick top(10) of records, what happens?

Consumer one gets first 10 records and changes their status to `Locked` and while it is using them, the second consumer tries to pick top(10) but it will be aborted:

> The current transaction attempted to update a record that has been
>   updated since this transaction started. the transaction was aborted.

With readpast lock we could say to the consumer 2 to pick second 10 records, instead of being aborted.

Comment: Do you really need to use memory optimized table for this?

Comment: With in-memory OLTP you always need to account for the possibility of aborts. It is not possible to always avoid them. Is your problem that there are too many?